# Assign different actions to a Floating Button on Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, floating-action-button, android-architecture-components

I have an application under construction using the Navigation Drawer Activity which is the one with the left menu like the old version of Google PlayStore:

[image]

As you know the design comes bundled with a FAB (FloatingActionButton):

[image]

Now, in the left side menu you see these three Fragments:

[image]

I wanted to know, how do I assign different actions to the FAB when I change the `Fragment`? From the `MainActivity` I see that there is the k but I do not understand how to assign a different functionality to it, since when changing the Fragment, the same `FAB` is still there and executes the same action that in this case is a Toast:

```
 binding.appBarMain.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Home Fragmen Visualizado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

The idea is, if someone can explain or tell me how I control the `FAB` action according to the `Fragment` it is in.

Comment: If you're trying to implement different click actions or functions when you are in a specific fragments you can get the current active fragment from fragment manager and use `switch` or |if.. else` to perform the action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the current fragment hosted by the `NavHostFragment` and decide what you need to do then with the fab.

```
binding.appBarMain.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        final NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment); // change `nav_host_fragment` according to yours 

        if (navHostFragment != null) {
            Fragment currentFragment = navHostFragment.getChildFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0);

            if (currentFragment instanceof HomeFragment) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Home Fragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else if (currentFragment instanceof SlideshowFragment) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Slideshow Fragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else if (currentFragment instanceof GalleryFragment) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Gallery Fragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    }
});
```

Also you can remove this fab, and put a fab in each fragment (HomeFragment, GalleryFragment, & SlidshowFragment) to be manipulated individually.

Comment: Thanks, this is that i need

Answer (score 0):

When you create new Navigation Drawer Activity, by default in the file named app_bar_main.xml Fab comes with it.

Its implementation is in MainActivity file.

you can change the implementation from here or can delete the code from these both files if FAB is not needed.

This file lies on top of mainActivity that's why it is showing in each fragment.

[image]
[image]

Comment: yes, i know but i don't know how to change the implementation when i change the fragment. Examole: i'm in mainactivity where homefragment, and i change the fragment with galleryfragment, so how i do to show differents toast with fab?...

Comment: For this you need to access FAB in your fragment and then add your own implementation.. , Or you can create some interface to capture the click from the current fragment.... Or introduce some global variable from each fragment will work for this purpose... , But Accessing FAB is the most recommended way...